# How to query Django LogEntry by content_type name?

Tags: django

I would like to query Django admin's LogEntry records by content_type.name.
I have tried this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
logs = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__name='foo')
```

But this results in the error trace of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 781, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 799, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1260, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1286, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/opt/sf/sf/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1211, in build_filter
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: name
```

I can do this ...

```
logs = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type=102)
logs.all()[0].content_type.name
u'foo'
```

... so how can I get all the content_type objects that have the name `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentType is composed of three columns id(integer), app_label(char), and model(char)

In this case, you probably want

```
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__model='foo')
```

Comment: Ah thanks! But where the heck did `content_type.name` come from?

Comment: Set as a property (ends up being useful to newcomers).

https://github.com/django/django/blob/dc5e75d419893bde33b7e439b59bdf271fc1a3f2/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py#L148

Comment: `ContentType.name` is a property that returns a localized verbose name. But it can't be used in a query, since it's not directly stored in the database.